# Wired internet is connected to internet, but no internet access!

Tags: internet

Yeah, In the bottom right corner it shows I'm connected and everything, but it shows that the internet isn't working. Wired that is; is not working. It always stops working at a certain time which is 9:00 o'clock. I use to have parental controls, but according to my step-dad it isn't there anymore. Can someone help?

Comment: What kind of "parental controls" were implemented?  And what did he do to remove them?  I presume 9:00 is when the (supposedly removed) parental controls would stop you from accessing the Internet?

Comment: Platform, version of Ubuntu, your level of skills?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways that he could be setting parental controls.  Either by things like OpenDNS or via your router, including others.  Router would probably be the easiest and make the most sense. So we can start there.

I'm not sure how old your router is but many new ones come automatically equipped with parental controls, and if you go to do a hard reset of the router it will actually turn the parental controls ON.

If you're not worried about getting in trouble with your father, my suggestion would be to go to the router and do a hard reset on the device.  You can find a reset button that can be accessed with a paperclip or pointed pen/pencil at the back of the device.  Hold the button down for 10/15 secs and it will hard reset the configuration settings.

There will also be a home configuration URL on the back of the device.  For example most(if not all) of Linksys routers are 192.168.1.1.  Input the URL on the back of the router into your web browser.  It will take you to a login page, USUALLY the username and password is "admin" and "password" respectively.  This is based on device model though, and can sometimes differentiate.

From here, you can access all the of the router settings and particularly, parental control settings.  Make sure all of these are set to OFF.

Now, if this is an actual application like a Time Keeping app or a parental control software application and your family uses the same computer...you could just search the computer for the application via root and disable/modify it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was from the main computer and he must've set it on the OpenDNS for the Router would shut down everyone right? so I'm presuming that it was set on the OpenDNS, but I could always ask him before hand so just hang in there guys.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one
Go to the  terminal and type

```
sudo gedit /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base
```

add following in file, save and close

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

restart the system.
It worked in my case.